# How to exclude controller from spring security?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have set up spring security which works fine, however in one of my controllers i dont want to have the request wrapped up in a securityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper...

how can i exclude the controller from spring security?

I have tried adding the following:

```
<security:intercept-url pattern="/nonsecureMenu**" filters="none" />
```

but it still does not work?

Comment: How does your controller's source code look like? What version of Spring Security do you use?

Comment: im using spring 3, its all annotated. What i really need to do is access the request object that comes from catalina, not the wrapped up one from spring one - securityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper.

Comment: what about <http pattern="nonsecureMenu**" security="none" /> ?

Comment: hi reagten, not sure about that as i do have some urls that need authentication. But will look into it and post back..

Comment: I added the parent security:http pattern but then my resources that needed authetnication stopped working..

Comment: @reagten Unless he's using Spring Security 3.1, it won't work.

Comment: @user1555190 Do you use SS 3.1? If not, your code should work (I mean no Spring Security filter should be applied at all). Can you turn debug on (add `log4j.logger.org.springframework.security=DEBUG` line to log4j.properties)?

Comment: im using 3.1.1.RELEASE, question when i set it to filters none, it fails to load the page..

Comment: So do what @reagten suggested. In 3.1.X `filters="none"` is not supported.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Comments are getting too long, so I write here what should you do.

Just as @reagten suggests, use this (and also add `/` in the beginning of path):

```
<http pattern="/nonsecureMenu**" security="none" />
```

declaring **separate** `<http>` element just for this path, i.e. you'll have more than one `<http>` element:

```
<http pattern="/resources/**" security="none" />
<http pattern="/nonsecureMenu**" security="none" />
<!-- plus for your actual config, for example: -->
<http auto-config='true'>
  <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
  <form-login login-page='/login'/>
</http>
```

Comment: excellent, @reagten - didnt know you could add multiple http elements. Thanks to both. cheers :)