# Which annotation shall I use to keep spring boot from securing my Controller when actuator is active

Tags: spring, spring-security, annotations, spring-boot

I wrote a simple spring boot application (with version 1.21) that publicly exposes data via REST. I activated actuator in order to get insight of what is happening in the application:

```
dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator")
```

On my development environment I set a fixed user / password:

```
security.user.name=admin
security.user.password=admin
security.user.role=ADMIN
```

Actuator causes Spring Security to be activated which also protects my Controller. This is not what I want, I want it to be called without the need to authenticate. When I call the Controller I see this message in the log:

```
11:00:40.713 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] INFO  o.s.b.a.audit.listener.AuditListener - AuditEvent [timestamp=Fri Jan 16 11:00:40 CET 2015, principal=anonymousUser, type=AUTHORIZATION_FAILURE, data={type=org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedExcep
tion, message=access denied}]
```

I read this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12458333/how-to-exclude-controller-from-spring-security) on stackoverflow but was unable to translate this into annotations. I tried to annotate my Controller with `@Secured("ROLE_ANONYMOUS")` and `@Secured("IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY")` but this did not work out. I think that this causes Spring Security still trying to authenticate the user but after that the roles he is in would not matter

Is there an annotation that I can define for my controller that will signal Spring Security to refrain from popping up a authentication box ?

First I tried to get along without adding Spring Security but when the jars are missing I get this message:

```
13:27:08.726 [main] ERROR o.s.boot.SpringApplication - Application startup failed
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not evaluate condition on org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.SpringBootWebSecurityConfiguration#ignoredPathsWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter due to internal class not found. This can happen if you are @
ComponentScanning a springframework package (e.g. if you put a @ComponentScan in the default package by mistake)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:51) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.2.1.RELEASE.jar:1.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConditionEvaluator.java:102) ~[spring-context-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
...
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:950) [spring-boot-1.2.1.RELEASE.jar:1.2.1.RELEASE]
    at demo.Application.main(Application.java:20) [bin/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/security/web/access/WebInvocationPrivilegeEvaluator
```

Application.java:20 looks like this:

```
ApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
```

Comment: Did you try `security.basic.enabled=false`?

Comment: BTW the Actuator doesn't add security unless it's on the classpath. So you must have added Spring Security as well.

Comment: I added my answer to my initial post because it didn't fit into the comment

Comment: I tried security.basic.enabled=false and do no longer need to authenticate when calling my Controller. So this one is solved. But I liked the idea of protecting the other urls so not everybody can see my beans, application.properties. That means basically I look for a way to unprotect my Controller but at the same time protect the actuator (I didn't state that clear enough before)

Comment: `security.basic.enabled=false` (if you do nothing else) will disable security on the endpoints that are not provided by the Actuator. I guess you broke that by trying to add your own filters?

Comment: sorry, I defined no filters at all

Comment: You did define at least one filter (because you have security enabled). The log line you pasted says the user was anonymous when accessing your endpoint, so that means it was intercepted by a security filter (it wouldn't be if you just stick with vanilla Spring Boot configuration).

Comment: Then I did this without knowing what I do. Which tells me I need to learn more about spring boot and security ... Fortunately the code is quite small so I will investigate. Is there a characteristic code snippet I can search for or is it possible to somehow dump the filters ? Will they be part of the beans ?

Comment: There is one filter that is a bean (containing a number of filter chains with different matching rules). Turning on DEBUG logging for org.springframework.security gives you a lot of useful information about how an access decision is made.

Comment: You could also just remove spring security and follow the advice in the stack trace you posted (don't use the default package).

Comment: I'm afraid I still don't quite get it. Is this what I shoud be looking for: `Object
bean:"securityFilterChainRegistration"
scope:"singleton"
type:"org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean"
resource:"class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/security/SpringBootWebSecurityConfiguration.class]"
dependencies:Array[2]
0:"springSecurityFilterChain"
1:"securityProperties"`

Comment: just a note: all my classes have a package set, so mentioning the default package seems to be a "default" hint

Comment: I guess you need to share more code then. A complete but minimal project would be best.

Comment: strange, after adding perf4j to build.gradle and refreshing I get this exception:

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not evaluate condition on org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.SpringBootWebSecurityConfiguration#ignoredPathsWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter due to internal class not found. 
This can happen if you are @
ComponentScanning a springframework package (e.g. if you put a @ComponentScan in the default package by mistake)

This one seems to be missing:
org/springframework/security/web/access/WebInvocationPrivilegeEvaluator

And no, I don't use the default package ;-)

Comment: I don't think anyone can tell what's happening without more information (a complete project would do it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the expertise of Dave Syer I was able to solve this problem.
I set `security.basic.enabled=false` in `application.properties` and removed spring security from my `build.gradle` file.

I already did this some days ago but obviously refreshing the project did not work and so the spring security jars stayed on the classpath without me noticing this. After a full rebuild of the project everything worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can declare

```
@Bean AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) {
        return auth.getOrBuild();
    }
```

provided you have already configured "AuthenticationManagerBuilder"