# Can only use "generated security password" for log in

Tags: security, spring-boot, spring-security

This is my SecurityConfig

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity ( securedEnabled = true )
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    public void configureAuth(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception{
        auth
            .inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser("tom")
            .password("password")
            .roles("ADMIN")
        .and()
            .withUser("user")
            .password("password")
            .roles("USER");

    }}
```

Even though I define in memory users I can't log in using them and I get a generated user password everytime I run the application and I'm pretty sure that, that isn't supposed to be happening.

I've tried the solutions that were posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30761253/remove-using-default-security-password-on-spring-boot?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) with no luck at all.

Application.properties has nothing changed in it and main application class is this default with no changes.

Comment: What version do you use? Spring Boot 1.x or 2.x?

Comment: I use 2.x version