# Spring security application giving No AuthenticationProvider found for org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, rest

I am new to spring boot. I am trying to implement a simple spring boot security with userdetailsservice in Spring Tool Suite(STS).

Below is the controller I used:

```java
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class HomeController {

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String home() {
        return("<h1>Welcome</h1>");
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/user")
    public String user() {
        return("<h1>Welcome user</h1>");
    }
}
```

And the Web security configuration code:

```java
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.NoOpPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;

@EnableWebSecurity
public class AppSecureConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    
     @Autowired 
      UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    
    @Autowired
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
         http.authorizeRequests()
         .antMatchers("/user").hasRole("USER")
         .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
         .and().formLogin()
         .and().logout().permitAll();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder getPasswordEncoder() {
        return NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance();
    }
    
}
```

I gave all the required dependencies in pom.xml.

So, I have added below line in application.propperties file, and now system is not generating security password.

```java
spring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.servlet.UserDetailsServiceAutoConfiguration
```

And I have included user details Service for credentials.
Below is user detail service class

```java
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class MyuserDetails implements UserDetailsService {

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String s) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        return new userPrincipal(s);
    }

}
```

and userPrincipal class

```java
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;

import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;

public class userPrincipal implements UserDetails {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String userName;
    
    public userPrincipal(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }
    
    public userPrincipal() {
    }
    
    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return Arrays.asList(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER"));
    }

    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return "pass";
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return userName;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return true;
    }

}
```

now, when I ran the application using http://localhost:8081/ url, it is giving "**No AuthenticationProvider found for org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken**".

I am using Spring tool suite(STS) to run this project. Can some one point out what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Add `@Configuration` to your `AppSecureConfig` class.

Comment: Does this answer of your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30761253/remove-using-default-security-password-on-spring-boot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not exclude the entire `SecurityAutoConfiguration`, instead if you want you should just exclude the `org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.servlet.UserDetailsServiceAutoConfiguration`.

Alternatively, you can expose a `UserDetailsService` bean that will do the same for you, and you can get rid of the `configureGlobal` method, like so:

```java
@Bean
public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
    UserDetails user = User.builder()
            .username("user")
            .password("password")
            .roles("USER")
            .build();
    return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(user);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your `application.properties`

```
spring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.SecurityAutoConfiguration
```

And your class will look like this:

1. Add @Configuration to the class (as suggested by M. Deinum)
2. Specify the role for the user, otherwise you will get `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot pass a null GrantedAuthority collection`

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class AppSecureConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    
    @Autowired
    protected void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("user").password("{noop}"+"pass").roles("USER");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
         http.authorizeRequests()
         .antMatchers("/user").hasRole("USER")
         .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
         .and().formLogin()
         .and().logout().permitAll();
    }

}
```