# Configuring LDAP on Spring Boot 3

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-data

I was experimenting with spring boot 3 and spring security 6.

I configured my spring security to use LDAP authentication via AD, which works fine, but spring boot still doesn't detect a custom 'AuthenticationManager' and generates its own password.

This is how I set up my LDAP authentication:

```java
@Autowired
public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.ldapAuthentication().userSearchBase(userSearchBase).userSearchFilter(userSearchFilter).contextSource()
            .url(url).managerDn(managerDn).managerPassword(ldapPassword);
}
```

Even after configuring ldap, this is what I get.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you must create a context source, which includes your LDAP url (url), your Manager DN or the Base DN from which your users belong (managerDn), your LDAP password to authenticate yourself / your app to the server, and, last but not least, the connection pooling flag for LDAP (setPooled), which is recommended if you have a large number of users.

```
@Bean
public LdapContextSource contextSource() {
    LdapContextSource contextSource = new LdapContextSource();
    contextSource.setUrl(url);
    contextSource.setUserDn(managerDn);
    contextSource.setPassword(ldapPassword);
    contextSource.setPooled(true);

    return contextSource;
}
```

Second, you must configure the authentication manager object, which will assist spring boot in recognising that you will be using LDAP for authentication.

```
@Bean
AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(BaseLdapPathContextSource contextSource) {
    LdapBindAuthenticationManagerFactory factory = new LdapBindAuthenticationManagerFactory(contextSource);
    factory.setUserSearchBase(userSearchBase);
    factory.setUserSearchFilter(userSearchFilter);

    return factory.createAuthenticationManager();
}
```

Finally, this is entirely optional. If you need to look up an LDAP user in your app, this interface will come in handy.

```
@Bean
public LdapTemplate ldapTemplate() {
    return new LdapTemplate(contextSource());
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can exclude the use the
`@SpringBootApplication(exclude= {UserDetailsServiceAutoConfiguration.class})` to stop the default password generation.
For any different ways if you want you can follow this thread.
[Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30761253/remove-using-default-security-password-on-spring-boot)